# datatables get value of column to use on another column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have four columns in jQuery datatables with server-side processing. The forth one is a non-database field for storing a delete link.

So this fourth column has link for URL/delete but I want is to grab values from first column(say id) and make link for forth column to URL/delete/id

I am not able to understand how to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sites').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
      {
        "mData": null,
        "sDefaultContent": "<a href=\"./delete\">Delete</a>",
        "aTargets": [ -1 ]
      }
    ],
        "sAjaxSource": "./getSites"
    } );
} );
```

As you can see i have three columns and forth one in non-database field. I want to append data from first column of each row to this non-database field

Comment: You really should provide an example of what you have already tried. Some sample HTML in a JSFiddle would also be nice so that the answers will be applicable to your HTML and not just guess-work:)

Comment: @user2686338 please edit your question an add the code you posted on your comment to the question itself.

Comment: You can use mData and mRender to create URL/link. See example in http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns